# Android ListView selector change background image and text color at the same time

Tags: android, listview

This is my selector xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/listview_bg" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listview" />
 <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/listview_bg" />   
</selector>
```

I want to change the background image and the color of the text at the same time,
how can I modify the xml code?

I have tried to add `android:color="#FFFFFF"` at each item lines, but it is not working.

Comment: have you set textcolor="your drawble"?

Answer (score 0):

What you show us is a **drawable** selector. So it will select the drawable following the state of the view (pressed, focused, ...).

You need to use the same pattern but for a color. Create a directory `color` in your `res` directory and inside that `color` directoy a file `selectable_color.xml`

In this file, put the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <item android:color="#00FF00" />
</selector>
```

So the selectable_color will be red when pressed and blue otherwise. Now in your textviews or buttons, use this color as usual `android:textColor:@color/selectable_color`. Now when the user will press view, its text color will change from blue to red.

However, if pressed is the not the state you looking for, don't hesitate to chnage it, it's the same thing as for the drawable.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the following code in my project:

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    /*Initialize values with values*/
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view_item,listItems);

    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 1");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 2");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 3");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 4");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 5");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 6");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 7");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 8");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 9");
    listItems.add("WebTouch Tab 10");
```

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tv_list_view"
android:textColor="#6699FF"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:paddingTop="10sp"
android:paddingBottom="10sp"
android:paddingLeft="5sp"/>
```

That way you can set the text color and font. I have no idea about the background color thing though.